# Not able to build the latest react-native code changes and show them up on the Expo App

Tags: react-native, expo

I have explained my question on this Expo forum here but no reply on it yet:
https://forums.expo.io/t/not-able-to-build-the-latest-code-changes-on-the-expo-app/39639

Please have a look at the question.

Comment: Are you sure you're saving the file?

Comment: yes, I am coding in VisualStudioCode editor and I am saving the file, running "expo start" command on the terminal, and scanning the QR code in the Expo App, but still nothing is getting updated.